# How to map related objects with a custom name for the foreign key property, like PostId instead of Post_Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

So I'm going to use the cliché example of a blogging database model with posts and comments.

```
public class Post {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Body { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Body { get; set; }
  public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, `Post` has a one-to-many relationship with `Comment`.

If I let Entity Framework create the database for me, it will add a `Post_Id` column to the `Comments` table. I would like to have the column named `PostId` instead, but I don't want to add a `PostId` property to my `Comments` class. Is there a way to achieve this via [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx), [DbModelBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), [migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx), something else I don't know about?

I apologize if this has already been answered, but I haven't been able to find it on SO or even Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And right after I post this, I find the answer.

Declare this method on the class derived from DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Post)
    .WithMany(t => t.Comments)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("PostId"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including the method this goes into - many answers don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with Annotations:

```
public class Comment {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Body { get; set; }

  public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Post")]
  public int PostId { get; set; }
}
```

The `ForeignKeyAttribute` takes one argument, the name of the navigation property for which this column is the foreign key.